Determine the number of permutations of the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that no three of the integers $1,2,3$ and $4$ appear consecutively.
I found this problem in A path to combinatorics for undergraduates. This is problem 9.49.
Determine, as a function of n, the number of permutations of the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that no three of the integers $1,2,3$ and $4$ appear consecutively.
I've tried 2 methods below.
Method 1: Inclusion-exclusion principle
We define the following:
$A_1=\{\pi \in S_n: 1,2,3$ appear consecutively in $\pi \}$
$A_2=\{\pi \in S_n: 1,2,4$ appear consecutively in $\pi \}$
$A_3=\{\pi \in S_n: 1,3,4$ appear consecutively in $\pi \}$
$A_4=\{\pi \in S_n: 2,3,4$ appear consecutively in $\pi \}$
Pick any $i,j,k\in \{1,2,3,4\}$ with no two equal.
To calculate $|A_i|$, W.L.O.G, let $i=1$, we permutate $n-2$ objects, a block of 3 consecutive integers and $n-3$ integers in $\{4,5,...,n\}$ minus the 3 integers that appear consecutively in $(n-2)!$ ways. Then we permutate $\{1,2,3\}$ in $3!$ ways. So $$|A_i|=(n-2)!3!$$
To calculate $|A_i\cap A_j|$, W.L.O.G, let $i=1$ and $j=2$, note that in any permutation in $A_1\cap A_2$, the integers in $\{1,2\}$ must appear in between the integers in $\{3,4\}$. We permutate $n-3$ objects, a block of 4 consecutive integers and $n-4$ integers in $\{5,6,...,n\}$ in $(n-3)!$ ways. Then we permutate the 2 integers in $\{1,2\}$ in 2! ways. Then we place those 2 integers in between $3$ and $4$ in 2 ways. So $$|A_i\cap A_j|=(n-3)!(2!)(2)$$
We now calculate $|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k|$, W.L.O.G, let $i=1$, $j=2$, $k=3$. For any $\pi \in A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3$, since $\pi \in A_1\cap A_2$ the integers in $\{1,2\}$ must appear in between the integers in $\{3,4\}$. Similarly, the integers in $\{1,3\}$ must appear in between the integers in $\{2,4\}$. However such a permutation pattern is impossible. So $$|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k|=0$$
In addition, we get $$|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3 \cap A_4|=0$$
By the inclusion-exclusion principle, we have
$$|\bigcap_{i=1}^4\bar{A_i}|=n!-\binom{4}{1}(n-2)!3!+\binom{4}{2}(n-3)!(2!)(2)$$
Method 2: We permutate the $n-4$ integers in $\{5,6,..,n\}$, then place the integers $1,2,3,4$ in the space this creates.
There are $(n-4)!$ ways to permutate the integers in $\{5,6,..,n\}$. We may place the integers $1,2,3,4$ in the following ways.
Suppose we partition the integers $1,2,3,4$ into 2 blocks, then place them. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to partition the integers $1,2,3,4$ into 2 blocks. Then we may permutate each block for $2!$ ways, for a total of $(2!)^2$ ways. There are $\binom{n-3}{2}$ ways to pick spaces for the blocks.
Suppose we partition the integers $1,2,3,4$ into 3 blocks, then place them. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to partition the integers $1,2,3,4$ into 3 blocks by choosing 2 integers to put in the block of size 2 and place the rest separately into the other 2 blocks. Then we may permutate the block of size 2 in $2!$ ways. There are $\binom{n-3}{3}$ ways to pick spaces for the blocks.
Suppose we partition the integers $1,2,3,4$ into 4 blocks, then place them. Clearly, there's only 1 way to partition the integers $1,2,3,4$ into 4 blocks. There are $\binom{n-3}{4}$ ways to pick spaces for the blocks.
Combining the above results, the desired number of permutations is $$(n-4)!(\binom{4}{2}\binom{n-3}{2}(2!)^2+\binom{4}{2}\binom{n-3}{3}(2!)+\binom{n-3}{4})$$
However the 2 formulae I've obtained above don't agree with each other. Could anyone tell me where I got it wrong? Thank you.

In the second method you forgot to allow the blocks to be permuted (e.g. with 3 blocks, there are 3! ways to put them in the set of 3 spaces that were chosen).

There are only three ways to partition the set ${1, 2, 3, 4}$ into two blocks with two numbers each since there are three ways to select which of the other numbers will be paired with $1$.

Thanks. Now I get that the correct formula for the 2nd method should be $(n-4)!(\frac{1}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{n-3}{2}(2!)^2(2!)+\binom{4}{2}\binom{n-3}{3}(2!)(3!)+\binom{n-3}{4}(4!))$

I'm answering this so I can accept an answer. Credit goes to @Jaap Scherphuis and @N. F. Taussig
Method $1$ is correct whereas Method $2$ is incorrect. Here is the correct way to proceed with method $2$.
Method $2$: We permutate the $n-4$ integers in $\{5,6,..,n\}$, then place the integers $1,2,3,4$ in the space this creates.
There are $(n-4)!$ ways to permutate the integers in $\{5,6,..,n\}$. We may place the integers $1,2,3,4$ in the following ways.
Suppose we partition the integers $1,2,3,4$ into $2$ blocks, then place them. There are $3$ ways to partition the integers $1,2,3,4$ into $2$ blocks with $2$ integers each since there are $3$ ways to select which of the other numbers will be paired with $1$. There are $\binom{n-3}{2}$ ways to pick spaces for the blocks. Then we may permutate each block for $2!$ ways, for a total of $(2!)^2$ ways. There are $2!$ ways to permutate the $2$ blocks.
Suppose we partition the integers $1,2,3,4$ into $3$ blocks, then place them. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to partition the integers $1,2,3,4$ into $3$ blocks by choosing $2$ integers to put in the block of size $2$ and place the rest separately into the other $2$ blocks. There are $\binom{n-3}{3}$ ways to pick spaces for the blocks. Then we may permutate the block of size $2$ in $2!$ ways. There are $3!$ ways to permutate the $3$ blocks.
Suppose we partition the integers $1,2,3,4$ into $4$ blocks, then place them. Clearly, there's only $1$ way to partition the integers $1,2,3,4$ into $4$ blocks. There are $\binom{n-3}{4}$ ways to pick spaces for the blocks. There are $4!$ ways to permutate the $4$ blocks.
Combining the above results, the desired number of permutations is $$(n-4)!(3\binom{n-3}{2}(2!)^2(2!)+\binom{4}{2}\binom{n-3}{3}(2!)(3!)+\binom{n-3}{4}(4!))$$
